# Destination Host Unreachable between Host and Guest kvm

Tags: networking, bridge

I have a Centos 7 server with a centos VM (qemu-kvm) in bridge mode, both with static ip.

My host network info is:

```
eno2
  ip:          10.0.0.11
  subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
  gateway:     10.0.0.2
```

My guest network info is:

```
eth0
  ip:          10.0.0.12
  subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
  Gateway:     10.0.0.2
```

In both host and guest the virbr0 is configured by default.

My problem is when i try to ping from host to guest and vice versa I get the message: "Destination Host Unreachable". but I can ping from another physical machine to host and guest without problem.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it!

https://www.furorteutonicus.eu/2013/08/04/enabling-host-guest-networking-with-kvm-macvlan-and-macvtap/
this site explains my problema and my solution.

Comment: could have been nice that you give your solution detailed instead of pointing out to documentation... thx

Answer (score 0):

At least the following works for Ubuntu: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2232093

In your `/etc/network/interfaces` ensure it's something like below:

```
# eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual


# kvm br0
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 10.0.1.175
    network 10.0.1.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 10.0.1.255
    gateway 10.0.1.1
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    dns-nameservers 10.0.1.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

This file assumes `10.0.1.175` is host address (former address of `eth0`), and the rest should be clear by analogy (subnet/network/gateway/nameserver).

Then reboot your host, or find a way to restart networking and get these settings applied without reboot.